# How do you loop in jquery with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I am trying to create a bookmarklet that will click each row and run some code on a timer. It takes a while for each tab to load. If I just focus on one row my code works it's when I try to make it loop that my issue come up.

My current thought process is

```
javascript:(function(){
var TableLength = $("#summaryTable tr").length;
var j=1;

nameOfFunction = function(){
if(j === TableLength){break;}
$("#summaryTable tr:nth-child("+j+")").click();
setTimeout(function(){
$i("#tab1")[0].click();
J++;},1000);
setTimeout(nameOfFunction,2000);
};
nameOfFunction();
})();
```

Where my previous idea was

```
javascript:(function(){
var TableLength = $("#summaryTable tr").length;
var j;

for (j=1; j < TableLength; j++){
setTimeout(function(){
$("#summaryTable tr:nth-child("+j+")").click();
setTimeout(function(){
$i("#tab1")[0].click();},1000);
}, 1000};
}
})();
```

The table has a heading so the first row is row 1 not 0.

Comment: You aren't calling `nameOfFunction()` on second last line. Missing the `()`. They aren't needed in the setTimeout because you are passing it in as a function reference to be called later. You also aren't incrementing `j` in the function version

Comment: Sorry that was my bad I didn't copy and paste all of my code correctly.

Comment: I looked at my code again and Charlietfl was correct I didn't have ```()``` my second problem was break is not usable. I was able to go with ```return false```

Answer (score 0):

aye, your code does not do what you say you want it to do.

```
let TableLength = $("#summaryTable tr").length;

let rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("summeryTable>tr")); //not 100% on the '>'
rows.forEach(row=>{
   if(i==0){}
   else
       {
       row.click();
       setTimeout(function()
           {
           $("#tab1")[0].click();
       },1000);
   }
   i++;
});
```

but even this won't work, because $("#tab1") seems to be a repeated id (a no-no) unless it is clicking the same element over and over... and not the newly generated tab///

should be $(`#tab${i/j/whatever iterator you use}` instead.

and I'm not sure if this is what you mean exactly. but that's the approach i would use.